# How to make IntelliJ know FIXME?

Tags: intellij-idea, comments, todo

In IntelliJ 12, the FIXME comment is regarded as a normal comment with typo. How to make it known by IntelliJ IDEA just like TODO comment?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Edit `TODO` pattern

In Settings/TODO press '+' to add a pattern, add the following pattern: `\bfixme\b.*`, assign an icon if necessary, apply changes. This should solve your issue.

[image: screenshot of Preferences > Editor > TODO > Edit Pattern]

Comment: The same settings section also exists for Android Studio as well. It is located within Settings/Editor/TODO. At least for current versions the fixme-pattern already is preinstalled though.

Comment: This also works for PyCharm ('fixme' is added by default, but you can add other patterns).